# Website registration works on XAMPP but not on my LAMP server

Tags: php

I've just finished setting up my remote server. setup LAMP, transferred my website over. I can login with a user fine but for some reason my code returns an error when inserting data. It goes through the code and does return an error if the user already exists, so I've determined it stops and returns an error after the line.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, password, hash) " 
            . "VALUES ('$user_name','$email','$password', '$hash')";
```

which in turn returns the error:

```
else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
        header("location: error.php");
    }
```

full code below.

```
 <?php
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name'];

    // Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
    $user_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    $hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

    // Check if user with that email already exists
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error());

    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

        $_SESSION['message'] = 'User with this email already exists!';
        header("location: error.php");

    }
    else { // Email doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, password, hash) " 
                . "VALUES ('$user_name','$email','$password', '$hash')";

        // Add user to the database
        if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

            $_SESSION['active'] = 0; 
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
            header("location: error.php");
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What does ``` $mysqli->error ``` say?

Comment: `$mysqli->error` not `$mysqli->error()`